# What type of animation does StackOverflow use for Tag Popup?

Tags: jquery, animation, tags, stack-overflow

Does anyone know what type of (jQuery?) animation does Stackoverflow use for its Tag popup? By Tag popup I mean when you hover over a Tag in Stackoveflow a popup appears, the animation starts from top left to bottom right, does anyone know which type of animation it uses?

Comment: Looks like `.show(time)` :D

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uromug/3/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.show( time )` method](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

### [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ihuhip/1/edit)

```
$('a.post-tag').hover(function(){
  
  var $this = $(this);
  var offset = $this.offset(); 
  var myPos = {X: offset.left, Y:offset.top+26}; 
  $('#tag-menu').css({left:myPos.X, top:myPos.Y, width:300, height:200}).show(400);
                                                                       // ^^^TADA !!
   
}, function(){
  
  $('#tag-menu').stop(1,1).hide();
  
});
```