# jQuery: How to make hidden div appear from top right

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, offset

Please checkout this jsfiddle, when I click on a tag anchor I want the tag menu (div) to appear next to the anchor element but from the TOP RIGHT instead of the TOP LEFT, I have tried playing with the offset but I have not been successful thus far.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
     <div id="tag-menu"></div>
 <span class="edit-tags-wrapper" style="float:right;">
   <a rel="tag" title="show questions tagged 'jquery'" class="post-tag" href="#">jquery</a>
<a rel="tag" title="show questions tagged 'animation'" class="post-tag" href="#">animation</a>
<a rel="tag" title="show questions tagged 'tags'" class="post-tag" href="#">tags</a>
<a rel="tag" title="" class="post-tag" href="#">stackoverflow</a>
```

JS:

```
  $('a.post-tag').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var offset = $this.offset(); 
  var myPos = {X:offset.left, Y:offset.top+26}; 
  $('#tag-menu').css({left:myPos.X, top:myPos.Y, width:300, height:200}).toggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
    .post-tag{
     background:#e0eaf1;
     border-right:1px solid #3E6D8E;
     border-bottom:1px solid #3E6D8E;
     padding:2px 5px;
     color:#4a6b82;
    }
    .post-tag{
     text-decoration:none;
    }

    .post-tag:hover{
     background:#3E6D8E;
     color:#fff;
    }

    #tag-menu{
     background:#666;
     position:absolute;
     display:none;
     box-shadow:0 2px 3px #000;
     border-radius:5px;
    }
```

or you can checkout the JSFIDDLE to run it:

http://jsfiddle.net/EBergman/xfVaT/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xfVaT/3/)**</kbd>

```
$('a.post-tag').click(function(){

  var $this = $(this);
  var offset = $this.offset();
  var thisW = $(this).outerWidth(); 
  var myPos = {X:offset.left+thisW-300, Y:offset.top+26}; 
  $('#tag-menu').css({left:myPos.X, top:myPos.Y, width:300, height:200}).toggle();
});
```

you need to take in account the menu width and the button `outerWidth()` to make that one work by simply doing: `X:offset.left + thisW - 300`

happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much roXon that is exactly what I wanted, you are a genius! I don't know if you remember but this is the demo you created a while back for another question I asked here.

Comment: @EricBergman ohh! thanks! really! wow! that's why your name was so familiar! You're welcome! (yes! and the demo was kinda familiar too :) )

Comment: @EricBergman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200320/what-type-of-animation-does-stackoverflow-use-for-tag-popup :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Use `$(window).width()` to know the screen size

http://jsfiddle.net/xfVaT/4/

```
$('a.post-tag').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var offset = $this.offset(); 
  var menuWidth = 300;
  var menuHeight = 200;
  var myPos = {X:$(window).width() - menuWidth, Y:offset.top+26}; 
  $('#tag-menu').css({left:myPos.X, top:myPos.Y, width:menuWidth, height:menuHeight}).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Right now it displays from TOP LEFT, I want it to Display from TOP RIGHT and your JSFIDDLE edit if you notice the tag-menu is not aligned with the tag element when you click on it. The Tag Menu should appear below the tag element, I want the BOTTOM RIGHT of the Tag Element to align with the TOP RIGHT of the Tag Menu Div.

Answer (score 0):

You specifically fix the #tag-menu left.

```
$('#tag-menu').css({left:myPos.X, top:myPos.Y, width:300, height:200}).toggle();
```

How about fixing it right?

```
$('#tag-menu').css({right:myPos.X+300, top:myPos.Y, width:300, height:200}).toggle();
```